# file_put_contents on binary data not working properly

Tags: php, image, zip

i'm trying to read a zip file and its working properly.now i want to get the contents(images) of the zip file.but the images are distorted..here's my code snippet:

```
while ($zip_entry = zip_read($zip))
{
    echo "<p>";
    echo "Name: " . zip_entry_name($zip_entry) . "<br />";

    if (zip_entry_open($zip, $zip_entry))
    $contents = zip_entry_read($zip_entry);
      $name=zip_entry_name($zip_entry);
    file_put_contents('uphoto/'.$i.'.jpg',$contents);

}
```

Comment: are you sure about: `echo "$contents<br />";` ?

Comment: echo "$contents<br />"; is not not necessary.i just put that code to check whether it works or not

Comment: I'd open the resulting `.jpg` file in a regular text editor to verify whether something does not belong there.

Comment: how would i know whether somthing should be there or not?@ÁlvaroG.Vicario

Comment: Maybe your zip file was never opened, since you are writing to file no matter is content there or not. Can you please post what is written in $contents variable.

Comment: ÿØÿàJFIFHHÿÛC     $.' ",#(7),01444'9=82<.342ÿÛC   2!!22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222ÿÀŠt"ÿÄ  ÿÄµ}!1AQa"q2‘¡#B±ÁRÑð$3br‚  %&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyzƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š’“”•–—˜™š¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª²³´µ¶·¸¹ºÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚáâãäåæçèéêñòóôõö÷øùúÿÄ  ÿÄµw!1AQaq"2B‘¡±Á #3RðbrÑ $4á%ñ&'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz‚ƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š’“”•–—˜™š¢£¤@Dexa

Comment: Honestly, it looks like a pretty good JPEG file. How exactly do you verify the file contents? What does "distorted" means?

Comment: the whole image is not displayed.all the images are of 1 kb size..only the upper part of the images are displayed.rest are just black@ÁlvaroG.Vicario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to create a new image:

```
$i = 0;
while ($zip_entry = zip_read($zip))
{
    $content = zip_entry_read($zip_entry, zip_entry_filesize($zip_entry));                                  
    $image = imagecreatefromstring($content);
    $filename = 'uphoto/'.$i++.'.jpg';
    imagejpeg($image, $filename);
    imagedestroy($image);
    echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($content) . '"><br />';
}
```

I used zip_entry_filesize() to define the size of the content which seems to be needed to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

It wont work as you are inserting < br /> in your image data. You can't display image on a webpage by just echoing its content. You should base64 encode it for example and put it in img tag. Then you can do something like:

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($content) . '"><br />';
```

Comment: Please see `file_put_contents()` in the previous line. That's what the OP is asking about.

Comment: you can ignore this line echo "$contents<br />";.i'm trying to save the images in a folder named uphoto using following code   file_put_contents('uphoto/'.$i.'.jpg',$contents);

Comment: Comment that echo "$contents<br />" was just for testing wasn't written when I wrote this answer. You can ignore this answer then.